# Может ли толпа быть организованной?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сегодня в новостях показали, как пассажиры поезда Москва - Симферополь пересаживаются на паром. Диктор сказал, что пассажиры организованной толпой направляются к парому. Слух резануло. А как по-вашему, толпа может быть организованной?

Comment: Вы намеренно используете дефис в сочетании слов «Москва — Симферополь». Или из-за отсутствия тире на клавиатуре? 

Comment: Нет, конечно, не намеренно. Невнимательность. Да и плохо умею пользоваться этой клавишей. То тире получится, то дефис. Попробую поправить.

Comment: И всё-таки такой термин существует в СОЦИАЛЬНОЙ ПСИХОЛОГИИ, хотя он и кажется неправильным сочетанием:Организованная толпа-толпа, имеющая ярко выраженную организацию, упорядоченность. Понятие введено Гюставом Лебоном, который считал такие формирования, как рота солдат и даже заседание парламента, разновидностью толпы. Лебон также употреблял термин одухотворенная толпа, подчеркивая, что у толпы возникает своя собственная душа.

Comment: В «Азбуке социального психолога-практика» есть понятия организованной и стихийной толпы,рассматривается процесс перехода организованной толпы в стихийную( в производственных коллективах  низкий уровень или задержка зарплаты, сокращения и увольнения, снятие с должности признанного руководителя, плохие условия труда приводят к стихийным забастовкам, митингам и более тяжелым последствиям).
Чем жестче структура и дисциплина организованной толпы, тем тяжелее последствия при превращении ее в стихийную толпу.-это из справочника, так что есть такой термин,диктор имел право так сказать

Comment: У  меня  тоже  тире  не  получается.  Или  дефис,  или  подчёркивание.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Организованной толпой - неправильное сочетание, что видно из словаря:

ТОЛПА,

1. мн. в зн. ед.
   Неорганизованное скопление людей; сборище. Огромная, шумная т. Собраться, сбиться в толпу. Затеряться в толпе.
2. только ед.
   Обыкновенные люди, масса в противоположность героям, выдающимся личностям. Кто-л. недоступен толпе.
3. Толпой, в зн. нареч. Сообща, все вместе. Т. возвращаться в город. Толпами, в зн. нареч.
   Массой, во множестве. Люди бегут т.

Таким образом, толпу обычно или связывают с неорганизованной массой людей или придают ей значение стихийной общности при совершении каких-либо действий. Если толпу организовать, то она перестает быть толпой.

В этом случае лучше сказать: "Пассажиры организованной группой направляются к парому".

Comment: Получается, третье значение все же подходит?

Comment: Я думаю, что в совместном действии не всегда присутствует  организация. Люди, например, могут бежать толпой, спасаясь от опасности. И в основном  значении слова заложен принцип неорганизованности.

Comment: Интересна этимология слова. Здесь выделяется и.-е. корень telp - быть емким, вместительным, а tolpa - это емкость. Схема развития значений следующая: помещение – люди в помещении – просто люди. В др.-рус. с 11 века "толпа" - это собрание народа. Во франц. языке есть слово foule - место, помещение, где жмут, давят.

Answer (score 5):

Выражение некорректное и закрепилось как шутливое. В словаре (Живая речь. Словарь разговорных выражений. — М.: ПАИМС. В.П. Белянин, И.А. Бутенко. 1994) зафиксировано:

**Организованной толпой (коровы шли на водопой)**

- о толпе, беспорядочном передвижении группы людей.

То есть смысл фразы противоположный: организованной толпой значит беспорядочно, потому что порядка от толпы не дождешься.

[См.:Живая речь. Словарь разговорных выражений](http://livespeak.academic.ru/1239/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9_%28%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%29)

Answer (score 4):

Такое
 сочетание возможно, но скорей всего не в данном контексте. Понятие 
"толпа" трактуется по разному. Некоторые исследователи понимают под 
толпой любые скопления людских масс с общими целями, например рота 
солдат. Воинское подразделение, если его считать толпой, как раз и будет
 толпой организованной.

Даже если принять эту достаточно спорную трактовку за истину, сильно 
сомневаюсь, что пассажиры двигались к парому в ногу под команду "Ать, 
два!". Скорей всего, подобное перемещение еще можно было бы назвать 
"организованной массой людей" или "управляемой (ведомой) толпой", да и 
то максимум, почти наверняка организации в этом движении было не больше 
чем при выходе людей из кинотеатра или метро, а это типчные примеры 
"стихийной толпы".

---

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), к сожалению не могу оставить комментарий, поэтому только так. Если все так, как вы описываете, то этот пассажиропоток в принципе можно назвать организованной толпой. Но нужно понимать, что подобный термин достаточно узкоспециальный и признается далеко не всеми учеными, не уверен, что подобное можно употреблять в публицистической речи без дополнительных пояснений или хотя бы указанием на то, что это термин или оксюморон.

Comment: Дело в том, что пассажиры выходят вместе с проводниками и направляются на паром, после парома снова садятся в те же вагоны (вещи остаются в вагонах, вагоны через пролив перевозит железнодорожный паром). Т.е. получается, что элемент какой-то организации присутствует?

Answer (score 2):

Если  достаточно  большая  группа  людей  не  построена  в  колонну,  то  это - толпа.  Если  эта  толпа  в  своём  движении  прислушивается  к  чьим - то  указаниям  ( голосовым  или  каким - либо  другим ),  то  элемент  организации  налицо.  При  этом  форма  толпы  может  быть  не  нарушена.  Если  она  будет  нарушена,  то  речь  пойдёт  о  разрозненных  группах  людей,  движение  которых  тоже  может  быть  организованным.

Comment: Оратор может зажечь толпу своими речами, сплотить ее вокруг какой-либо идеи, направить на какое-либо действие, но всё это просто объединяет толпу в единый организм без какой-либо внутренней организации.  Толпа перестает быть толпой, когда ее начинают делить на группы, подчиняющиеся конкретным указаниям. Только тогда этот единый организм теряет общий стихийный дух и распадается на части.

Comment: Речь  не  об  ораторе,  а  об  руководителе,  который  стоит  себе  с  на  крылечке  с  мегафоном  и  указывает  порядок  и  направление  движения,  поправляет  если  что  не  так.

Comment: Делить  на  группы  при  это  не  обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Толпящаяся масса народа, толпы.
Движущаяся масса народа, толпы.
Уже говорит нам о наличии элемента хаотичного движения, неупорядоченного. Мы же не можем назвать хаос немножко упорядоченным. Понятие толпа применяется к скоплению людей с хаотичным их перемещением, стоят они или движутся, в разном направлении или в одном. Иначе перемещение организованной колонной, группой, строем. Если движение упорядочено, то, организованное кем бы то ни было движение уже нельзя назвать толпой.

Answer (score 0):

ТОЛПА это "бесструктурное скопление людей, лишенных ясно осознаваемой общности целей, но связанных между собой сходством эмоционального состояния и общим элементом внимания" (http://enc-dic.com/sociology/Tolpa-9002/).
Другими словами: масса людей (с поезда) без общих целей (едут кто зачем) в  состоянии волнения (где же море?) искали глазами паром (как Ноев ковчег)...
Итак, это действительно толпа. Поскольку существует общий элемент внимания - паром, движутся они в направлении к нему. Эту толпу кто-то должен был направить, то есть организовать: указатели ("Выход к парому через переход"), "бывалый" ("Идите за мной!"), звуковое оповещение ("Пассажиров, прибывших поездом из Москвы, просим пройти на паром"). Вот вам и ОРГАНИЗОВАННАЯ ТОЛПА...